# Fetch information from an Oracle Database stored procedure in PHP

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE seleccionar (
    registros  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
    codigo     NUMBER
) AS
BEGIN
    OPEN registros FOR SELECT
                           nombre_producto, 
                           precio_producto,
                           imagen
                       FROM
                           producto
                       WHERE
                           id_categoria = codigo;
END;
```

I am using this stored procedure to extract that information from my oracle database

This is my php page

```
<?php
$conn = oci_connect('ProyectoLBD', 'ProyectoLBD', 'orcl');
$mi_cursor = oci_new_cursor($conn);
$e = oci_error($conn);
$sql = 'BEGIN seleccionar(:registros,1);end;';
$query = oci_parse($conn,$sql);
oci_bind_by_name($query, ":registros", $mi_cursor, -1, OCI_B_CURSOR);
oci_execute($query);
oci_execute($mi_cursor);
while(($row = oci_fetch_array($mi_cursor,OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS))!=false){
    echo json_encode($row);
}
?>
```

But the information is never printed

```
{"IMAGEN":"https:\/\/cr.epaenlinea.com\/pub\/media\/version20200605\/catalog\/product\/cache\/a83b746ef25730b9cb1cc414bac0f04a\/1\/5\/1585056_9.jpg","NOMBRE_PRODUCTO":"Set de 3 reflectores led","PRECIO_PRODUCTO":"5,495"}{"IMAGEN":"https:\/\/cr.epaenlinea.com\/pub\/media\/version20200605\/catalog\/product\/cache\/a83b746ef25730b9cb1cc414bac0f04a\/1\/5\/1582460_19.jpg","NOMBRE_PRODUCTO":"Set de 2 bombillos cfl","PRECIO_PRODUCTO":"4,495"}{"IMAGEN":"https:\/\/cr.epaenlinea.com\/pub\/media\/version20200605\/catalog\/product\/cache\/a83b746ef25730b9cb1cc414bac0f04a\/1\/5\/1582457_21.jpg","NOMBRE_PRODUCTO":"Set 2 bombillos cfl","PRECIO_PRODUCTO":"2,95"}{"IMAGEN":"https:\/\/cr.epaenlinea.com\/pub\/media\/version20200605\/catalog\/product\/cache\/a83b746ef25730b9cb1cc414bac0f04a\/1\/5\/1578081_1.jpg","NOMBRE_PRODUCTO":"Set de 3 bombillos vintage","PRECIO_PRODUCTO":"7,95"}{"IMAGEN":"https:\/\/cr.epaenlinea.com\/pub\/media\/version20200605\/catalog\/product\/cache\/a83b746ef25730b9cb1cc414bac0f04a\/1\/5\/1583142.jpg","NOMBRE_PRODUCTO":"Bombillo globo black vintage","PRECIO_PRODUCTO":"29,995"}{"IMAGEN":"https:\/\/cr.epaenlinea.com\/pub\/media\/version20200605\/catalog\/product\/cache\/a83b746ef25730b9cb1cc414bac0f04a\/1\/5\/1580032.jpg","NOMBRE_PRODUCTO":"Bulbo mercurio","PRECIO_PRODUCTO":"5,45"}{"IMAGEN":"https:\/\/cr.epaenlinea.com\/pub\/media\/version20200605\/catalog\/product\/cache\/a83b746ef25730b9cb1cc414bac0f04a\/1\/5\/1583133.jpg","NOMBRE_PRODUCTO":"Bombillo led disco","PRECIO_PRODUCTO":"5,95"}{"IMAGEN":"https:\/\/cr.epaenlinea.com\/pub\/media\/version20200605\/catalog\/product\/cache\/a83b746ef25730b9cb1cc414bac0f04a\/1\/5\/1585057.jpg","NOMBRE_PRODUCTO":"Bombillo led e27 para exterior","PRECIO_PRODUCTO":"8,995"}{"IMAGEN":"https:\/\/cr.epaenlinea.com\/pub\/media\/version20200605\/catalog\/product\/cache\/a83b746ef25730b9cb1cc414bac0f04a\/1\/5\/1583009_18.jpg","NOMBRE_PRODUCTO":"Bombillo led filamento decorativo","PRECIO_PRODUCTO":"4,75"}{"IMAGEN":"https:\/\/cr.epaenlinea.com\/pub\/media\/version20200605\/catalog\/product\/cache\/a83b746ef25730b9cb1cc414bac0f04a\/1\/6\/1650941.jpg","NOMBRE_PRODUCTO":"Bombillo inteligente de luz blanca","PRECIO_PRODUCTO":"8,495"}{"IMAGEN":"https:\/\/cr.epaenlinea.com\/pub\/media\/version20200605\/catalog\/product\/cache\/a83b746ef25730b9cb1cc414bac0f04a\/1\/6\/1650943.jpg","NOMBRE_PRODUCTO":"Bombillo inteligente de luz blanca para exteriores","PRECIO_PRODUCTO":"9,45"}{"IMAGEN":"https:\/\/cr.epaenlinea.com\/pub\/media\/version20200605\/catalog\/product\/cache\/a83b746ef25730b9cb1cc414bac0f04a\/1\/5\/1583069.jpg","NOMBRE_PRODUCTO":"Bombillo led torpedo filamento","PRECIO_PRODUCTO":"3,45"}{"IMAGEN":"https:\/\/cr.epaenlinea.com\/pub\/media\/version20200605\/catalog\/product\/cache\/a83b746ef25730b9cb1cc414bac0f04a\/1\/5\/1583101.jpg","NOMBRE_PRODUCTO":"Bombillo led estilo vintage con escala rgb de 1,5","PRECIO_PRODUCTO":"5,995"}{"IMAGEN":"https:\/\/cr.epaenlinea.com\/pub\/media\/version20200605\/catalog\/product\/cache\/a83b746ef25730b9cb1cc414bac0f04a\/1\/5\/1578071.jpg","NOMBRE_PRODUCTO":"Bombillo incandescente decorativo filamento","PRECIO_PRODUCTO":"3,45"}
```

That's the answer I get but that format doesn't look like JSON

Comment: Put the `echo` statement inside the loop.  Add some [error checking](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-error.php) after each call. Add  debug echo statements

Comment: When I put the echo statement inside the loop the information was printed but the JSON format did not work

Comment: Update your question and show what it being displayed, and tell us what you want the output to be like.

Comment: I already edited it for you to see

Comment: Each row looks like a JSON string.  You may want to print a newline between rows to confirm.